# Wget website "drilling" for radio show elements

Tags: wget

I run a Low Power FM community radio station and in addition to the live shows, we carry syndicated programs from producers around the world.  Every week I spend way too much time downloading show elements and putting them in their respective folders for the Win 10 automation to play.

Some come via RSS, some by FTP, others from email links, and more than a few are accessed through websites (some public, some with passwords).  I've played with Windows programs like *Internet Download Manager*, but I bet I can speed things up by having a dedicated Linux-based PC use wget and cron to handle some of the weekly duties.  I'm still learning how to work with these, with an eye toward downloading only the newest files.

I've gotten *wget* to work on some sites without a hitch; others are going to require some patience, research, and detective work.  The thing I can't **begin** to figure out is how to handle those sites where I have to "drill down" to get to the latest content.  The URL of the most recent files changes week-to-week.  Take a look at this:
[Picture of hierarchy of web "drilling"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PIbt.jpg)

I go to the main page (for example, h++p://www.***radioshow***.org/stationdownload/index.php) which leads me to another page, where I choose the file format I want (.mp2, .mp3, etc.), which leads me to another page where I choose which date I want, which leads me to another page wherein I can find this weeks files for downloading.

I've proved that wget will handle individual files from such a site without issue, but can't figure out how to tell the program to drill down to get to the appropriate directory and download the new files every week.

I'm not a full-on noob, but also not experienced enough to be able to say, "Pssshh! A child could do it!" or "Are you crazy?  It doesn't work that way!"

Thoughts?

Comment: While I'm no wget expert, that sounds like a job for a web scraper, not wget. I would generally tackle the problem by writing a python script that follows the necessary links, and then maybe use the subprocess module to call wget for the individual downloads, or download directly using the python script. Other languages might have a similar methodology if you are familiar with them, but I'm not sure how one would go about it using just wget or bash tools.

Comment: There is no standard way for these websites to provide what you want (if there were, we would call that an API) and the way to drill down will be different from one radio station to another. Moreover, it may be changed at any time without notice. If you nevertheless want to download these items, you would write a small program that 1) loads a web page; 2) using a HTML library, parses the page to find the link that you need; and 3) repeat until you get what you are looking for. And hopefully, the website doesn't get changed by next week. Feasible, but time-consuming.

Comment: Possible off-topic question.  I don't see how this relates to Ubuntu, or official flavors of Ubuntu. Only w10 & Linux-based is mentioned; we don't support windows 10, nor generic GNU/Linux based systems (SE's Unix & Linux supports that).  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: [This question on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117988/wget-with-wildcards-in-http-downloads) talks about using wildcards with wget. If there is a pattern with something like the 191214-PDQXY that changes, you should be able to use wildcards to tell wget to only download the file if certain parameters are matched or not matched. The [wget manpage](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-features) "filename wildcard matching" mentions this. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options-1).

Comment: @guiverc It still applies to all users using `wget` on Ubuntu.

Comment: The "patterns" mentioned use regex and you can specify either [pcre](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC1) or [posix](https://linux.die.net/man/7/regex) using the `--regex-type` option. Regex is pretty simple (but powerful) once you get used to it and there are tons of examples if you google these or you can ask a question later if you need help with the regex part.

Comment: Thanks all, for the advice and info! @guiverc, I wouldn't be here if I weren't talking about Ubuntu or an Ubuntu-fork.  The question is not OS-specific, but thanks for the welcome mat!

Comment: Ubuntu-forks (*Mint, Elementary* etc) are **off-topic** on this site. Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (downloaded from Ubuntu - https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours)  are on-topic here https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You have many solutions for your need : download some pages source code, compute them to find the files you want OR browse URLs based on names & dates. Ubuntu wget and curl are your friends. Consider using regular expressions